# Skipping Devise Route Registrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am trying to skip and add my own custom routes for registrations in devise but it seems not to work and i keep getting an error.

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do

   namespace :api do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
    end
end
```

When i rake routes, i still get the initial devise routing for registrations. How can i customize my registrations routes. especially for new.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb`?

Comment: Yes, that's is for the api namespace, but what else do you have in your routes.rb in terms of devise? I assume that you are using gem 'devise_token_auth'. what kind of error are you getting and what does your post request that rails look like?

Comment: this is all i hv in my routes and my error is The action 'new' could not be found for DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController when i run this route GET "/api/auth/sign_up"